# Wordpress caching - using W3 Total cache with CloudFront vs using CloudFront directly

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, w3-total-cache

If you have already deployed your wordpress instance to AWS, which scenario for CDN makes more sense?

1. Using CloudFront directly on top of a LoadBalancer.
2. Using CloudFront with W3 Total Cache plugin?

Answer (score 1):

If you expect high volume of traffic to your WordPress website the better option will be the first one:

> Using CloudFront directly on top of a LoadBalancer.

If you are in the beginning of your project the better option will be the second one:

> Using CloudFront with W3 Total Cache plugin?

Also please note that you are comparing server architecture and configuration versus plugin. Which are two completely different things. These two completely different things can also work together with no issues (if configured properly of course) and you will have the next setup:

> Using CloudFront directly on top of a LoadBalancer with W3 Total Cache plugin.

Another hint: if you are in the beginning of your project or not familiar how to configure complex plugin with many options such as [W3TC](https://wordpress.org/plugins/w3-total-cache/), I would recommend you cache plugin with less options and more simple. Recently, I have started using [WPCacheOn](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpcacheon/) recently on all of the websites, I am using and I am very happy with it. Simply install and activate the [WPCacheOn](https://wpcacheon.io/) and no further configurations or settings are needed for faster website.

I hope this information helps you in choosing your setup and cache plugin for your project.

Comment: Hmm. I highly doubt that using Cloudfront directly and W3 Total Cache backed by CloudFront would even make sense.